# Git on Windows - Cannot clone from UNC path

Tags: git

I thought I could clone from a UNC path, alas no.

```
D:\Git>git clone \\M0218\Git\SomeProject
Cloning into 'SomeProject'...
fatal: '\M0218\Git\SomeProject' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ugh; I thought that closing would require 5 votes.  This certainly feels like a dup of several other questions, but I think this one is compelling as it is the most directly asked and answered.  Please do holler (or vote to reopen) if you think this was closed wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use forward-slashes `/` !

```
git clone //M0218/Git/SomeProject
```

That's it.

Comment: Or use `\\\\M0218\...`